# Executing oracle store procedure using entity framework 5

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-5

Store Procedure is

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GETCORPORATEACTION(
RECORD_DATE IN date,
prc out sys_refcursor
)
AS
BEGIN
OPEN prc FOR SELECT *
FROM HR.CORPORATEACTION
where RECORDDATE = RECORD_DATE;
END;
```

Calling SP using EF:

```
var CorporateActions = db.GETCORPORATEACTION(recordDate);
```

> Error is Message = "ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:\nPLS-00306: wrong
>   number or types of arguments in call to
>   'GETCORPORATEACTION'\nORA-06550: line 1, column 8:\nPL/SQL: Statement
>   ignored"

Kindly anyone suggest me how to get rid out of this problem.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your procedure has two arguments (`RECORD_DATE`and `pcr`), but you only call it with one param: `recordDate` - add the second param and ... Bazinga

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems:

1. The procedure being invoked takes two arguments but only one has been supplied. A variable for the second parameter should be given in the call.
2. This is a procedure which is being called. Procedures do not return a value, but you've coded the call as if a function is being called.

The call should probably be something like

```
db.GETCORPORATEACTION(recordDate, CorporateActions);
```